# Files Excluded by Defender. Are these files safe and can be excluded?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, windows-defender

When doing a scan of my laptop using Windows Defender on latest version of Windows 10, I notice there are few files are excluded by Windows Defender. You can view the image here:

[image: File List]

Are these files safe to keep on the laptop or we can delete it without any issues?

Looking for advice.

Comment: Looks like malware that whitelisted itself. It's certainly not normal.

Comment: Is this a corporate laptop?

Comment: No, this is a personal laptop used for development. How do I get rid of these? Also, do you advice me deleting these files?

Comment: that looks like a KMS activation crack to activate Windows.

Comment: That's weird! Its a laptop running original Win10 licensed via MS.

Comment: the last 2 files are not part of original Windows 10. Run [slmgr.vbs -dli](https://serverfault.com/a/709880/197546) to see which activation you use (OEM, retail or KMS)

Comment: it shows as a KMS client. how do I get rid of this?

Comment: buy a legal Windows 10 license, enter the product code and delete the 2 non MS files from system32